# Exchange 2010 reply with history

Tags: email, exchange-2010, reply

I Would like to know if there's an option for this:

When the user replay to a mail in exchange 2010 sp1, all the content of the discussion is put in the mail.

One of my user don't want this.

Is there an option by user or maybe a global option.

Thanks
hope i'm clear, if you need more info just comment i'll try to answer fast as i can

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK, this is a feature of the email client, not Exchange itself.